# Object Disappears in Wireframe and Solid view (not Dev look or rendered)

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view

So I just opened up my saved file from last night to find that my cup object, as well as the plane, are completely gone if I switch my view to Wireframe or Solid view. However, it is there and all is fine if I view it in Dev Look and Rendered view. I am new to Blender, yet I have tried small commands like 'hide/unhide' etc.
On a similar note, my plane is only represented by a small portion of itself and when I try to grab and move it, it scales for some unknown reason.

I am currently using the latest 2.81 Beta version and understand if this is some horrible bug.

Any help is very welcome. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you hit alt+b accidentaly. Hit again. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with <kbd>Alt+B</kbd>too.